# IBAction button crashes when using it the second time without changing view

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I'm building a notes app saving the notes to a NSUSerDefaults after the click of a button. Well when I load that view and add the note and click on the button to save it the first time, it works properly. However if I don't leave the view and add a new message and try to click the button to save it, my app crashes. which I really don't understand why. The xcode version I'm using right now doesn't give me a lot of details on my errors, but I do see this

```
0x00015a9b  <+1175>  xor    %eax,%eax
Program received signal 'SIGABRT'
```

This is the code of the IBAction that is triggered after the button click (sent event)

```
-(IBAction)saveNote{
NSUserDefaults *prefs=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//If empty add text to synthesized array and then add the array to the USer defaults
if([[prefs stringArrayForKey:@"Subjects"] count]==0){
    NSLog(@"Went through here");
    [notesSubject addObject:writeNote.text];
    [prefs setObject:notesSubject forKey:@"Subjects"];

    NSLog(@"The length of the array is %d",[notesSubject count]);

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Note Saved" message:@"Your note was saved" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    //[notesView.tableView reloadData];

}
//If not empty, get the array stored in the user defaults and set it to a temp array, add text to that temp array and then place the temp array back to the user defaults.
else{
    newSubjects=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    beforeSubjects=[[NSArray alloc]init];

    newSubjects= [prefs stringArrayForKey:@"Subjects"];
    [newSubjects addObject:writeNote.text];
    [prefs setObject:newSubjects forKey:@"Subjects"];
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Note Saved" message:@"Your note was saved" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    //[notesView.tableView reloadData];
}


}
```

Yeah, I don't really understand why the app crashes on second click.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the mutable `newSubjects` instance with an immutable instance with this line:

> newSubjects= [prefs stringArrayForKey:@"Subjects"];

Instead, it should be this:

> newSubjects = [[prefs stringArrayForKey:@"Subjects"] mutableCopy];